# Bootstrap: hover in a grid to pop-out another grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am wondering there's an easy way to click a grid then it will make appear another grid? I am still trying to figure out a way to do this. i am stuck...

unclick

[image: hover out]

click

[image: Hover in]

Here's the code, there's a container and a footer with 12 grid, I am trying to figure out if there's a way to hide the 11 grids from the right if i unclick the first grid, then click the first grid to make appear the rest of the grids in the right

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

.container {
  width: auto;
  
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.container .text-muted {
 
}

.btn-sq-xs {
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
 
}
```

```html
<html >
  <head>
    <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>-->
    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Container</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      
    
    <div class="row show-grid">
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? You may be able to use the general sibling combinatory (~)

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Please show what you have attempted and explain the specific error you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your HTML looks like, you might be able to do something like this:

And then in CSS:

```
.hover-target {
    display: none;
}
.hover-trigger ~ .hover-target {
    display: block;
}
```